# Resotre deleted login page on DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

I dont know how but I deleted my login page and now I cant login to my DNN site. When I go to `http://mydomain/Home/tabid/36/ctl/Login/Default.aspx` where the login should be it shows blank container with no username and password to enter. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to load the login control. This works even if the login page is deleted:

http://mydomian.com?ctl=login

You can then create a new login page or retore the old page from the recycle bin.

Answer (score 0):

tricky stuff...?ctl=login did not work for me, if login page is deleted but still remains in recycle bin of website. The standard login works again as soon as the custom login page is deleted from recycle bin.

You could try the following if 
- portal registration is public and you have 
- write access to sql database / dnn table dbo.users:

Go to your portal register page, 
- add a new user (stay logged in)
- connect to dnn database i.e. via SSMS, 
- open table dbo.users and 
- find new registered user, set: IsSuperUser to True.

Finally reload portal page (F5), go to recycle bin, make empty or restore login page.
If you don't have superuser write access after page refresh, restart your site in IIS and refresh page.